# Can't run any google scripts that requires permission in my personal account only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example I can't run this code in my personal account.

```
function myFunction() {
  Logger.log("teste")
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UljL.png)

I'm familiar to going to advanced options when I'm giving permissions and allow it, but its not showing anymore.
It looks like I need to configure something but I don't know what. I have tried the same process in other account and it's working fine.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you signed in with multiple accounts? If so, please sign out of all but one or try in Incognito.

Comment: @ziganotschka tried that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It seems to be a bug, other users have a already reported this issue on Google's Issue Tracker.

I recommend you to "star" the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/176138626) to increase its visibility and hopefully accelerate the fixing process.